# Query on associated value in sails

Tags: mysql, node.js, sails.js

There are two tables, Books which has many-to-many association with Tags.
How can the Book that have only particular tag id be found? 
I tried:

```
Book.find().populate("tag", where:{id: 1 }).exec(console.log)
```

But it gives all the books.

Comment: Yes, this query will return all books, and populate their `tag` arrays, but filter those arrays so that only tags with `id == 1` will show up.

Comment: Although not a standard way but if you have significantly high number of  books (say a million) and concerned about performance, the most efficient way of doing this would be by Model.query and using a native SQL query (assuming your underlying database is SQL database) and have appropriate indexing in the database tables

Answer (score 2):

If your looking for all books with a specific tagid, your going to want to do something like:

```
Tag
.findOne(1)
.populate('books')
.then(function(tag) {
    if (!tag) {
        res.serverError(error);
    } else {
        res.json(tag.books);
    }
});
```

Basically you want to look up the tag by id (1), and then populate the `books` association for that tag.

Comment: Thanks @jason , can the same result be achieved by using query on the Book table itself, as other additional filtering also needs to be done   on the book..

Comment: You can do querying in the populate `.populate("books", {where: { category: category_id }})`

Comment: Tried that too, all it does is, filters the populated  values within that particular item..

Comment: well you're trying to do a an and query right? where tag ==1  and book.category == "scifi". if you want to loosen up the restrictions set by the findOne, you can do a `Tag.find({id:[1,3,66,74,23]}).populate...`

Answer (score 0):

You must provide criteria in `find()`, not in populate.

Your fixed variant:

```
Book
    .find()
    .where({
        id: 1
    })
    .populate('tag')
    .exec(function(error, books) {
        if (error) {
            res.serverError(error);
        } else {
            res.json(books);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I want to search for books with specific populated value of tag id, not book id